# Varying ESLint handling for mjs, js, and ts files

Tags: typescript, eslint, commonjs

My project uses ESM (.mjs) files for server-side code, CommonJS (.js) for tooling, and TypeScript (.ts) for the client.

When viewing CommonJS files in VS Code, errors are being shown for requires..."Require statement not part of import statement.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires."

This is a good rule for the .ts files but not for CommonJS.

Here's my ESLint config from my package.json...

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/typescript/recommended",
      "@vue/prettier",
      "@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2020
    },
    "rules": {
      "prettier/prettier": [
        "error",
        {
          "semi": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
          "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "jest": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Any thoughts as to how I should structure it applies TypeScript rules to .ts, CommonJS rules to .js and ESM rules to .msj?

Comment: You are already using `overrides`, can you not continue with that?

Comment: This was an auto-generated config by vue-cli. I am just picking through the override capability now. Yeah, looks like an override can be used in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ESLint Docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/plugins#specifying-processor) suggest using `overrides` and specifying the `files` array for the file types you'd like to handle.